# GreaseMonkey: GM_xmlhttpRequest return value to calling function

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

ive been messing round with this for hours and im pulling my hair out at it. How do I return var a from myFunction to allow it to be set as var b which and then display the value of b in the alert message? Thanks! :)

```
function myFunction(arg)
{
var a;

GM_xmlhttpRequest({
  method:"GET",
  url:"http://site.com/arg?" + arg,
  headers:{
    "User-Agent":"monkeyagent",
    "Accept":"text/monkey,text/xml",
    },
  onload:function(details) {
    a = details.responseText;


  }
});

return a;

}

b = myFunction("blabla");
alert(b);
```

When I tried it returned just a blank message.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return `a` like that because `GM_xmlhttpRequest` operates asynchronously.

The onload function will fire long after `myFunction` has returned.  Anything that you want to do with `a` will have to be done from functions called within the onload function.

Greasemonkey ***just*** added support for synchronous mode, starting with version 0.9.9.   If you must, you can download the prerelease of version 0.9.10, [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/versions/).

However, you would be smart to learn to handle this kind of thing asynchronously.  You will get a faster, more responsive UI instead of "hangs" and "freezes".  It's a good concept to grok for all manner of real-life programming situations.

Comment: so how to return a for use outside the xmlrequest?

Comment: @龚元程, you would use code like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8778267/331508) -- except that last I checked, bugs in Greasemonkey keep it from working.  It's better to not code that way at all.